# EXTJS 3.0 populate combobox with store (typeError b[e] is not a constructor)

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I am working with EXTJS 3.0 I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out exactly what this error mean and why I keep on receiving it

typeError b[e] is not a constructor

I am attempting to populate a combo box from a store. unfortunately the code is on a system that I can not copy the code to this site but I am implementing the most basic example of doing this provided from the site

```
 // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [
    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    //...
]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
store: states,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'abbr',
applyTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

I know this is not providing much info but if you could point me in some directions as to what may cause this error it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor (b[d.xtype || e] is not a constructor)
```

This happens when trying to instantiate (create) a component that does not exist, the most common reason is a typo or spelling error.

I tried todo the same thing. The only exception being that I created a form and then included the combobox. It is working fine.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    title:'Sample form',
    layout:'fit',
    renderTo:document.body,
    items:[{
        xtype:'combobox',
        store: states,
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'
    }]
});
```

The store remains the same:

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
            {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
            {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
            {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
           ]
});
```